# generate fixed sequence for a given seed in linux

Tags: linux, random, fixed

I want to generate fixed a sequence of numbers that change with "seed" in linux. I am doing it with the following command.

```
export USR_SEED=91; export SEQ_START=53; export SEQ_LENGTH=15; bash -c 'RANDOM=$USR_SEED; for((i=1;i<=$SEQ_START;i++)); do echo -n $RANDOM >/dev/null; done; for((i=1;i<=$SEQ_LENGTH;i++)); do echo -n "$RANDOM "; done; echo'
```

This give a fixed sequence every-time I ran it, but the sequence changes when I do it on a different machine. Is there a way to generate a fixed sequence of numbers every-time I ran it, irrespective of machine (64bit, 32-bit linux platform).

-Mohan

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on a few linux machines running:

- 3.8.0-23-generic, ubuntu, x86_64, bash version 4.2.45(1)-release
- 2.6.32-5-686, debian, i686, bash version 4.1.5(1)-release
- 2.6.32-5-amd64, debian, x86_64, bash version 4.2.37(1)-release

in each case if I used the same seed I had the same results.

Check to see if you're running different bash versions or if anything else strange might be interfering with your results.  It should work exactly as you said.

Comment: Iam running the following cmd on Fedora-16(32-bit) and fedora-18(64-bit) and i am getting different results. export USR_SEED=91; export SEQ_START=53; export SEQ_LENGTH=15; bash -c 'RANDOM=$USR_SEED; for((i=1;i<=$SEQ_START;i++)); do echo -n $RANDOM >/dev/null; done; for((i=1;i<=$SEQ_LENGTH;i++)); do echo -n "$RANDOM "; done; echo'